# kwargs different behavior

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Dear pythonist that question is for you!
I don't ask to solve my task, just ask for explaining why it happens)
I know what is args and kwargs when they using but has been really shoked, when have found one thing. So, please check my example, here we pass arguments to the function

```
def firstFunc(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args' )
    print(args)
    print('kwargs')
    print(kwargs)
    
firstFunc([1, 2], {'firstFirst': 'firstFirst', 'first' : '123', 'second' : '999'})
```

[image: And thats the result of it, all that we passed we have in args, but kwargs is empty, first of all why we don't have kwargs as dictionary like that we have passed ?]

My second question is, why we can get the dictonary  from the second function,
if we will set it like this  kwargs['second'] = 222,
that's my code

```
def firstFunc(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args' )
    print(*args)
    print('kwargs')
    print(**kwargs)
    kwargs['second'] = 222
    secondFunc([1, 2], **kwargs)


def secondFunc(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args' )
    print(args)
    print('kwargs')
    print(kwargs)



firstFunc([1, 2], {'firstFirst': 'firstFirst', 'first' : '123', 'second' : '999'})
```

[image: but my second function seing kwargs dictonary, how i set it in the first function]

hope I described understandable, I am waiting for u answer, please tell me why it hapens, and why I cannot just pass dictionarie as kwargs!
many thanks for u

#python #pythonic #kwargs #args #functions

I expected just mine dictionary in kwargs

Comment: To use `kwargs` without expanding the dictionary then do `firstFunc(firstFirst='firstFirst', first='123', second='999')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the list and the dictionary as two positional arguments, so those two positional arguments are what shows up in your `*args` in the function body, and `**kwargs` is an empty dictionary since no keyword arguments were provided.

If you want to pass each element of the list as its own positional argument, use the `*` operator:

```
firstFunc(*[1, 2])
```

If you want to also pass each element of the dictionary as a keyword argument, use the `**` operator:

```
firstFunc(
    *[1, 2],
    **{'firstFirst': 'firstFirst', 'first' : '123', 'second' : '999'}
)
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
firstFunc(
    1,
    2,
    firstFirst='firstFirst',
    first='123',
    second='999'
)
```

Comment: and syntax like this - kwargs['second'] = 222
does it for us, I mean putting **?

Comment: `kwargs['second'] = 222` just sets the value of the `'second'` key in the `kwargs` dict.

Comment: thanks sounds very meaningful, it seems  like when you calling an object without (), 
u just call for the reference not  for example of the object

Comment: Honestly I would recommend not using `*args` or `**kwargs` *at all* until you're more comfortable with defining regular Python functions.  Having a function take variable arguments is something that's only useful in certain situations and if you don't already understand the basics it's just going to slow you down.  It seems like you're muddling different concepts together and defining a function doesn't need to be as complicated as you're making it here.  :)

Comment: only now found that i passed to the second function with ** 
you explain me everything, thank you for this)

Comment: i understand that data structure and object, it is different things, 
but i remember how i didn't understand that if i call object without (), it such different thing, but there is same thing about syntax when u don't use right syntax it will confuse you)
just i reading now book about python (python tricks) and there is about args and kwargs

Comment: it all happened because python very laconic, thats why if you admit little mistake it will change the behavior, when at same time at other language you will got en error

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys !
I found the difference when I passing arguments, that for first function I didn't passed ** with argument(applied expanding), but for second functtion I passed it(applied expanding), just my syntax mistake. but what conclusion when we can make - that if u passing dictionarie as kwargs always use **(always expand it), otherwise it will be just element of the list(*args)
Best regards to all!